# Why can't I modify class member variable outside any methods?

Tags: java, member

I have a class with some variables. When I instantiate an object of that class in the main class. I can only access and modify member variables in a method, any method; not outside them. Why is that? I am stuck and can't seem to find an answer on google.

```
class SomeVariables{
    String s;
    int dontneed;
}
class MainClass{
    SomeVariables vars= new SomeVariables();

    vars.s = "why this doesnt work?. IDE says Uknown class 'vars.s'";
    System.out.println(vars.s);        // Accesing it also doesnt work

    void ChangeValue(){
        vars.s = "why does this work?";
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
    }
}
```

Also I tried access specifiers and got the same result

Comment: In java, statements must be in code blocks (methods, constructors, static or instance initialization blocks), not in the body of a class.

Comment: thank you sir. Am new to java

Comment: @ernest_k Since this is an answer, why don't you post it as one?

Comment: @KyleWilliamson Because he voted for *"close as duplicate"*. See meta [Answering a question, then closing it as duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286072/answering-a-question-then-closing-it-as-duplicate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work  because you are defining the instances outside of a constructor or methos which is not valid Java syntax.

A possible fix would be:

```
class SomeVariables {
    String s;
    int dontneed;
}

class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        SomeVariables vars = new SomeVariables();

        vars.s = "why this doesnt work?. IDE says Uknown class 'vars.s'";
        System.out.println(vars.s);
    }
}
```

But you might want to consider protection of your class variables such are making all attributes og the `SomeVariables` and use `setters` and `getters` methods to get and modify the value in the class itself. For example:

```
class SomeVariables {
    private String s;
    private int dontneed;

    // Constructor method
    public SomeVariables() {
        // Initialize your attributes
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return s;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        s = value;
    }
}

class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        SomeVariables vars = new SomeVariables();

        vars.setValue("Some value");

        System.out.println(vars.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a super simplified answer, if you want more details just add a comment ;)

```
class SomeVariables{
    String s;
    int dontneed;
}
class MainClass{
    // this is ok
    SomeVariables vars= new SomeVariables();
    // not allowed here, must be on method, main for example
    vars.s = "why this doesnt work?. IDE says Uknown class 'vars.s'";
    // not allowed here, must be on method, main for example
    System.out.println(vars.s);        // Accesing it also doesnt work

    void ChangeValue(){
        // it works because is on scope and inside a method
        vars.s = "why does this work?";
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        // here sholud be your statements var.s = ... and System.out.println
    }
}
```